# Ao dividir projeto em vários headers ocorre o erro: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, header

Estava querendo saber como dividir um projeto em vários arquivos. Tinha criado um projeto dividido em 3 arquivos primeiramente, um main.c (contendo função main), um lib.c (implementação das funções utilizado no main.c) e um lib.h (contem os protótipos das funções), "unindo" os arquivos utilizando #include "lib.h" no main.c e lib.c - e funcionava perfeitamente.

Porem, agora preciso dividir o projeto (o mesmo que terminei usando apenas 3 arquivos) em mais arquivos, ex: main.c, lib1.c, lib1.h, lib2.c, lib2.h ... sendo que quase todas as função continuam sendo as mesmas. Mas agora não consigo 'fazer funcionar' e recebo mensagens como:

> *"error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"*

Gostaria de saber como "juntar" esses arquivos quando compilar.

Mais informações sobre meu projeto: Muitas das funções utilizam implementações que estão em outros "arquivo.c". Estou utilizando o CodeBlock e o DevC++. Um **exemplo** de como esta o codigo agora:

***main.c:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"
#include "lib3.h"
...

int main()
{
...
   [uso das funções...]
...
}
```

***lib1.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"
#include "lib3.h"
...

struct item1{
   ...
};

ITEM1* funcao1(ITEM2* lista, int valor)
{
...
}

ITEM1* funcao2(ITEM1* lista)
{
...
}
...
```

***lib1.h***

```
typedef struct item1 ITEM1;

ITEM1* funcao1(ITEM2* lista, int valor);
ITEM1* funcao1(ITEM1* lista);
...
```

***lib2.h***

typedef struct item2 ITEM2;

```
ITEM2* funcao5(...);
...
```

**... (outros arquivos.c e arquivo.h)**

Como faço isso funcionar?

Comment: Po, quem edito ai minha pergunta edito errado, juntos as bibliotecas. TEM MAIS DE UMA LIB... LIB1.H, LIB2.H, LIB3.H...

Comment: Hobbit a edição do @L. não parece ter removido nada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/160260/2, todavia se algo ficar errado é só editar novamente, a edição só ocorreu porque você usou os StackSnippets sem necessidade. Ps: Eu editei o titulo para ficar mais intuitivo ao problema ;)

Comment: @Hobbit Eu só normalizei seu post, não removi nada, você só postou o trecho de 2 arquivos `.h`, `lib1` e `lib2`

Comment: Já editei, todavia posso ter me enganado, nesse caso desculpe-me.

Comment: Entendi oque esta errado. Deve colocar os structs dentro dos arquivos .h, pois é como se o main.c sabe que existe um typedef struct mas não sabe oque tem no struct.. (mais ou menos isso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O main está chamando o lib1.h e tentar compilar typedef struct item1 ITEM1;
Mas o lib1.c ainda não foi chamado para declarar a strutura.
O arquivo lib1.c ainda vai ser chamado para a compilação. Ou seja você não pode usar typedef struct para uma estrutura que ainda não existe.
A solução deveria colocar a declaração no header e vc usa typedef no .c
Fui claro?

### Aqui vão algumas dicas no seu código:

O main está chamando os arquivos header e o lib1.c também chama os mesmos arquivos. Imagina que você tenha 50 arquivos .c isso significa que os 50 arquivos vão chamar o header.
Resolver:
Use a diretive #define
Exemplo lib1.h:

```
#ifndef LIB1
#define LIB1
/* lembra de mudar essa linha */
typedef struct item1 ITEM1;

ITEM1* funcao1(ITEM2* lista, int valor);
ITEM1* funcao1(ITEM1* lista);
...
#endif
```

Main chama o lib1.h. ifndef (if = se, n = não, def = definido) ele executa o código dentro da ifndef e lá ele define o LIB1.
Quando o lib1.c chamar o mesmo arquivo ele vai fazer de novo o teste ifndef que o main já rodou e já definiu com uma constante LIB1, ele ignora todo o bloco de código.
Esses macros com # é usado para compilação, portanto abuse delas que elas servem para isso mesmo.
**Fui claro?**